# How many ouputs can be supported by ffmpeg simultaneously

Tags: ffmpeg

I know ffmpeg can create multiple outputs simultaneously with encoding one input source. But anyone know what is the upper limit can it support?

Answer (score 1):

There's no formal limit, but command line character limit imposed by shell or wrapper can impose a limit on outputs as well as practical constraints such as available threads, RAM, I/O..etc.